# Retrieving an array from a file and find it's size C

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof, maxlength

I have a file that I have to read some numbers from and put them into an array. The only problem is that I don't know how to find the size of it. I am given the maximum size of the array but the numbers don't fill the array completely. I tried many different ways to make it work but it doesn't read the correct values from the file. Is there any other way to do it without sizeof?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER 25
int main(void)
{
int test[];
int size;

FILE* sp_input;    
int i;
sp_input = fopen("a20.dat", "r");

if (sp_input == NULL)
  printf("\nUnable to open the file a20.dat\n");
else
  {
  while( fscanf(sp_input, "%d", &test[i])!=EOF)
  {
  size=sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]);
  }

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)

  printf("\na[%d]=%d has a size of %d\n", i,test[i],size);
  fclose(sp_input);    
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `i` isn't initialized and never changes value in your while loop.

Comment: If `size` is supposed to be how many numbers are in the array, why don't you just start it at 0 and increment it for each number you read?

Comment: Also, you need to give the number of elements for `test`, eg. `int test[MAX_NUMBER];` -- the array will always have the maximum number of elements, but you can keep track of how much of it you're actually using with `size`.

Comment: this line: `int test[];` does not compile!  suggest: `int test[ MAX_NUMBER ];

Comment: this line: `while( fscanf(sp_input, "%d", &test[i])!=EOF)`  is using the variable `i` without it being initialized, so it contains what ever trash was in memory at the location of `i` on the stack.  AND `i` is not being incremented to traverse through the array `test[]`  Suggest: `i = 0; while( i<MAX_NUMBER && 1 == fscanf(sp_input, "%d", &test[i]) ) i++;`

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr` rather than `stdout` (and when the error is from a system function, it is a good idea to output the reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Rather than: `printf("\nUnable to open the file a20.dat\n");`  suggest: `perror("\nUnable to open the file a20.dat\n");`. followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: this line: size=sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]); will always produce that exact same value. Note that sizeof() is a compile time operator not a runtime operator.  Suggest elimination of that line.

Comment: for the `for()` loop suggest inserting the statement: `size = i;`  so the variable `size` will be correct for the second parameter in the `for()` loop

Answer (score 2):

If you increment `i` each time you successfully do a `fscanf`, it will serve as a count of the number of items read.

```
i = 0;

while (fscanf(sp_input, "%d", &test[i]) == 1) {
    i = i + 1;
}

// Now, i is the number of items in the list, and test[0] .. test[i-1]
// are the items.
```

**Edit:** As @chux pointed out, in this case it's better to compare to 1, the expected number of items scanned, on each call. If a bogus input is provided (non-digits), there's still a problem and you should stop.

Comment: Minor `fscanf(sp_input, "%d", &test[i]) == 1` is more idiomatic as the loop continues as long as the results are as expected rather than 1  of other possible `fscanf()` results.  Of course in this case only `EOF` or 1 is expected, yet this axiom applies with more complex scans.

Answer (score 1):

Define a maximum size array and continue looping as able.

File input need not *fill* the array, just populate it as it can.  Keep track, `i`, of how many of `test[]` was used and be sure not to overfill the array.

```
#define MAX_NUMBER 25
int test[MAX_NUMBER];

FILE* sp_input = fopen("a20.dat", "r");
...

// Use `size_t` for array indexing    
size_t i;
// do not read too many `int`    
for (i=0; i<MAX_NUMBER; i++) {
  if (fscanf(sp_input, "%d", &test[i]) != 1) {
    break;
  }
  printf("test[%zu]=%d\n", i, test[i]);
}
```